# Grafana : How can separate alerts between error and timeout?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I would like to ask for expert here to help on my Grafana alert setting.. 
Now i did set alert on one of my graph but i want the alert between timeout and threshold hit to be separated.. because it seems it are all together now and it makes miss judgement on if we need to check or not.

Or if i can increase my timeout will be great!!!..
i use Grafana version 4.1.2 with Carbon-cache (graphite DB).

please see attached picture that it comes together ..

IF EXECUTION ERROR OR TIMEOUT --> need this to be separated.

[Grafana alert setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf9UM.png)

Comment: i checked grafana.log i found this :alert" error="tsdb.HandleRequest() error context deadline exceeded" changing state to=alerting

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible atm.

You can set `If execution error or timeout` to `Keep last value` to avoid getting errors on timeout. But then you would not get alerting on errors.

The default timeout for alert queries is **30 seconds**. Are you sure there query is working as expected?

We might make the timeout configurable in the future but if your query cannot complete within 30 seconds I would worry more about the query.

Comment: I see.. how can i fix that query issue? i had checked in Query log of Carbon and found some connection lost.. but i am not sure if it is cause or not because time does not match to alert.. Any suggestion? By the way. i had updated carbon and whisper to latest version.. but still issue alert happens